# How did Batman change his armor?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

I've just watched [Batman V Superman: Dawn of Justice](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2975590/) and have a question.
Batman's suit was pretty damaged in his battle with Superman but then he had brand new armor while flying in the Batplane.

**When and where did Batman get the new armor after his fight with Superman?**

Comment: Is there an especially good reason to assume he didn't have a spare suit stashed in the bat-plane? He was going to go fight Superman so there's a pretty good chance he'll need a change of clothes afterwards...

Comment: @valorum especially pants :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Valorum hinted at, I'm pretty sure it's safe to assume that Batman is capable of storing at least one suit of armor in most of his (bigger) vehicles.

For example, in *Arkham Knight* he uses the Batwing to deploy a full set of upgraded armor with a drop pod, directly ejected from the passing by plane.

[image: Armor pod from *Arkham Knight*]

Comment: Good point. Sadly it's not shown in the movie.

Comment: @GinoPane It's probably the superhero equivalent of *nobody poops*. :)

Answer (score 1):

Probably dropped the armoured suit. Because Batman was wearing an under-suit while wearing the armoured suit. And after the fight, he dropped it off inside the Bat-plane and we see him wearing the under-suit or in other words, his usual crime fighting suit.